# Xpages Debug Toolbar overrides my bootstrap UI

Tags: xpages

I've just started using Mark Leuksink's XPages Debug Toolbar (along with his Bootsrap4Xpages plugin). The Toolbar works well, but my Bootstrap UI has been overridden.

[image]

I've tried setting disableTheme="true", but no bananas. I've inserted the debug Toolbar just under the resources tag of my appLayout Custom Control.

Is there something I can do about this?

I'm using OpenNTF Bootstrap Library for XPages 1.0.0.201407020945 and XPages Debug Toolbar 1.0.0.20143092102

```
<xp:view
xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
xmlns:bx="http://www.openntf.org/xsp/bootstrap"
viewState="fulltree"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
xmlns:debug="http://www.openntf.org/xsp/debugtoolbar">
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script
        src="/commonjavascript.jss"
        clientSide="false">
    </xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
<debug:toolbar
    defaultCollapsed="false"
    collapseTo="left"
    disableTheme="true"
    autoRemove="true">
</debug:toolbar>
```

Comment: What does "my Bootstrap UI has been overridden" mean? Are the Bootstrap CSS files not loaded?

Comment: I'm using both plugins, so I'm not including some css files separately. I imagine there are custom renderers for both plugins, and they are biting each other. I'm not sure how to say 'plugin toolbar, don't make some extra rendering'. This is just an assumption, I'm not sure how it works internally.

Comment: Which versions of those plugins are you using? I'm using the latest versions of all of them. i don't use the XPT lib though. No problems with the debug toolbar & Bootstrap & appLayout with bx-configuration.

Comment: Added the versions I'm using in the main text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh. Duuh. Major Dunce Cap.

Under XSP Properties, Theme defaults, Application theme, the bootstrap theme was no longer correctly inputted.

Per and Oliver, sorry for that!

Feeling sheepish right now.